# Google Drive API v3 update an object if one exists with same name: list 'q' parameter does not work as documented?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to update a file if it exists in a particular folder and has a specific name. In this instance the object in question is in a team drive. I followed documentation to compose the `q` parameter to the `list` call, tried to switch back to v2...It seems that the query is composed exactly correctly. That being said, even though I see multiple objects present in the target folder, the list call fails to see them. I've tried `name = ''` and `name contains ''`. There seems to be enough input validation put in place by the google team, as when i get creative the API bombs. Any pointers?

```
def import_or_replace_csv_to_td_folder(self, folder_id, local_fn, remote_fn, mime_type):
    DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    query = "'{0}' in parents and name = '{1}'.format(folder_id, remote_fn)
    print("Searching for previous versions of this file : {0}".format(query))
    check_if_already_exists = DRIVE.files().list(q=query, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
    name_and_location_conflict = check_if_already_exists.get('files', [])
    if not name_and_location_conflict:
        body = {'name': remote_fn, 'mimeType': mime_type, 'parents': [folder_id]}
        out = DRIVE.files().create(body=body, media_body=local_fn, supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='id').execute().get('id')
        return out
    else:
        if len(name_and_location_conflict)==1:
            file_id=name_and_location_conflict['id']
            DRIVE.files().update(fileId=file_id, supportsTeamDrives=True, media_body=local_fn)
            return file_id
        else:
            raise MultipleConflictsError("There are multiple documents matching parent folder and file name. Unclear which requires a version update")
```

When i tried to replace the 'name' parameter to 'title' (used to work in v2, based on some answers I reviewed) the API barfed

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%27+in+parents+and+title+%3D+%27Somefile_2018-09-27.csv%27&fields=files%28id%2C+name%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

Comment: Review the Drive API documentation on working with Team Drive items. You must take extra measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @tehhowch,

Indeed extra measures are necessary when the target in a team drive, namely  includeTeamDriveItems option needs to be set, otherwise TD locations are not included by default:

```
   check_if_already_exists = DRIVE.files().list(
       q=query, 
       fields="files(id, name)",
       supportsTeamDrives=True,
       includeTeamDriveItems=True
   ).execute()
```